# How to assign value from properties to enum C#

Tags: c#, enums

I have enum:

```
 public enum DiamDivide { Absolute, ByDivide }
```

and propertis with (Absolute, ByDivide) value  from database.

```
public string CalcMethodName { get; set; }
```

How to assign value from string properties CalcMethodName to enum DiamDivide?

Comment: Why don't you change CalcMethodName to be `public DiamDivide CalcMethodName { get; set; }`? That way you don't have to add extra conversion logic?

Comment: I connect the library from the database with the calculation code that someone wrote, so I have to assign values ​​from the database to this enum

Comment: And you have no control over changing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because database records could be compromised that's why blindly converting the string to an enum value might be error-prone.

A better approach could be to use `TryParse` and specify ignoring case:

```cs
if(Enum.TryParse<DiamDivide>(CalcMethodName, true, out var enumValue))
{
  //use enumValue
}
```

Even though it seems good, under the hood it [uses reflection](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/enum.cs#L367). So if the conversion is called many times then a single mapping would be better alternative:

```cs
private static readonly ImmutableDictionary<string, DiamDivide> Mapping = 
    new Dictionary<string, DiamDivide> {
        { nameof(DiamDivide.Absolute).ToLower(), DiamDivide.Absolute},
        { nameof(DiamDivide.ByDivide).ToLower(), DiamDivide.ByDivide}
    }.ToImmutableDictionary();

...
if (Mapping.ContainsKey(CalcMethodName.ToLower()))
{
  var enumValue = Mapping[CalcMethodName.ToLower()];
  //use enumValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert string to enum

```
string calcMethodName = "Absolute";
DiamDivide diamdivide= Enum.Parse<DiamDivide>(calcMethodName);
```

Comment: There is [an overload that simplifies this with generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Enum_Parse__1_System_String_). It becomes `DiamDivide diamdivide = Enum.Parse<DiamDivide>(calcMethodName);`

Answer (score 0):

Above answer would work, you can also try this (.NET Core / .NET Framework ≥ 4.0 ):

```
Enum.TryParse(CalcMethodName, out DiamDivide diamDivide);
DiamDivide = diamDivide;
```

`diamDivide` is your parsed enum value. Also, the method itself returns bool which indicates if the provided value was succesfully parsed, so you can check for it:

```
if(Enum.TryParse(CalcMethodName, out DiamDivide diamDivide))
{
    DiamDivide = diamDivide;
}
else
{
    //log error
}
```

[TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=net-5.0)